# Print the list of members in a voice channel

Tags: python-3.x, windows, discord, discord.py

i'm coding a discord bot and I need a function that kick all members in my channel. I wrote this code:

```
@client.command()
async def separaci(ctx):
    canale = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    utenti = canale.members #This return an empty list
    for utente in utenti:
        await utente.edit(voice_channel = None)
```

I don't know why `canale.members` return an empty list. Can you help me? Thanks you :)

Comment: It means that no one is in the voice channel, I guess

Comment: No, we are 6 in the voice channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
@client.command()
async def separaci(ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice: # if the author is connected to a voice channel
        canale = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        utenti = canale.members #This return an empty list
        for utente in utenti:
            await utente.edit(voice_channel = None)
        await ctx.send("Kicked all the members from the voice channel!")
    else:
         await ctx.send("You need to be in a voice channel!")
         return
```

---

#### NOTE:

- You need to be in a voice channel while using this command.
- Make sure the bot has the permission to disconnect the members present in the voice channel.
- Make sure you have the `members` intent enabled in your [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications).

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable member intents, also make sure to enable them in the [developer portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications)

```py
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True 

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='', intents=intents)

@client.command()
async def separaci(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    members = channel.members
```

- [A Primer Gateway to Intents](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html?highlight=intents)