# With statement discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

```
with ctx.message.author.voice.channel.members as users:
                for user in users:
                    await user.edit(voice_channel=None)
```

Gives this error:

```
with ctx.message.author.voice.channel.members as users:
AttributeError: __enter__

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: __enter__
```

I get the same error with: `with ctx.author.voice.channel as channel:`

I looked at discord.py documentation but i didn't find anything useful

P.S. this code was working one/two month ago, and "randomly" stopped working when i tried to restart the bot

Comment: What is the purpose of the context manager? What are you trying to achieve? And no, it didn't "randomly" stop because it should never work in the first place

Comment: I don't know the discord API at all, but `channel.members` does not strike me as something that would support a context. Maybe this will help get you unblocked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64891313/print-the-list-of-members-in-a-voice-channel

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński i'm only trying to cleanup code and be more clear. I am sure this was working, but surely too this hasn't stopped working randomly.

Comment: Are you trying to define a variable? `users = ctx.message.author.voice.channel.members`?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński probably this is the best way, yes, But i was only curiout about the fact that it was working. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just want to define a variable:

```py
users = ctx.message.author.voice.channel.members
for user in users:
    await user.edit(voice_channel=None)
```

If you want to use a context manager use `contextlib.nullcontext`:

```py
from contextlib import nullcontext

with nullcontext(ctx.message.author.voice.channel.members) as users:
    for user in users:
        await user.edit(voice_channel=None)
```

Also to disconnect a user from a voice channel you use `Member.move_to` with `None` as the argument, not `Member.edit(voice_channel=None)`

```py
await user.move_to(None)
```

#### References:

- [`contextlib.nullcontext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.nullcontext)
- [`Member.move_to`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.move_to)