# New programmer having trouble setting up a discord bot in discord.py to return amount of members in a voice channel

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am a new developer and have been trying to make a discord bot that would react to a discord command to see how many people are in the voice channel that the command came from(the author) and then it would pick a random game from a list depending on the amount of people in it. I have deleted and rewrote a bunch of stuff and I am very confused. Thank you so much for your time I am very lost on how to set up the functions.

I am using replit

```
import discord
import os
import requests
import json
import random


client = discord.Client()

game_list = ["League of Legends", "Valorant", "Valheim", "Apex Legends", "Tarkov", "Age of Empires", "Halo", "CSGO", "Seige" ]

print(random.choice(game_list))

def get_game():
  return(random.choice(game_list))



@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return
 
  voice_channel = message.author.voice.channel

  msg = message.content
  
  def game_plz():
    return(voice_channel.members())
  
  if msg.startswith('!game'):
    await message.channel.send(get_game())

  if msg.startswith('!plz'):
    await message.channel.send(game_plz())




#@client.event

#async def 
#channel = client.get_channel()
#members = channel.members()
#memids = []
#for member in members:
#  meids.append(member.id)
#print(meids)

client.run(os.environ['token'])
```

Comment: So is `game_plz()` suppose to return how many people are in a channel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since [`discord.VoiceChannel.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.VoiceChannel.members) is a list of [`discord.Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.Member) objects, you can check how many of these are within the list by using [`len`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_len.asp). Do also take note that `channel.members` is not a function on its own, and you do not need to include the `()`. Do view the revised code snippet below, as well as any further explanations.

```py
# I'm suggest putting this outside of the on_message event
def game_plz(channel:discord.VoiceChannel):
    members = channel.members #finds members connected to the channel
    # channel.members is a list of discord.Member objects
    return len(members) # returns amount of members in the channel

# within your on_message event
    voice_channel = message.author.voice.channel
    msg = message.content

    if msg.startswith('!plz'):
        await message.channel.send(game_plz(voice_channel))
        # pass voice_channel as an argument into game_plz
        # voice_channel should be a discord.VoiceChannel object
```

[image: Working image example]

**Other Links**:

- [Getting a list of all of the members in a specific voice channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50084002/discord-py-getting-a-list-of-all-of-the-members-in-a-specific-voice-channel) - Stackoverflow
- [Retrieve list of members in channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63367489/retrieve-list-of-members-in-channel-discord-py-rewrite) - Stackoverflow
- [**`INTENTS`** Print the list of members in a voice channel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64891545/14420546) - Stackoverflow

Comment: Thanks so much I've been struggling on just that part for like a week, is there a place i could look for all the discord.py commands and etc?

Comment: @kiyo I'm unsure what you mean by 'discord.py commands' exactly, but I do recommend visiting the [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for most problems 